# Unable to build Nuxt with Typescript support

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is the first time I am trying out Typescript with Nuxt (v 2.6.1).
I have a fresh build with create-nuxt-app and have followed the official guide for [Typescript Support](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/typescript/)

```
npx create-nuxt-app first-app
cd first-app
npm install -D @nuxt/typescript
echo "{}" > tsconfig.json
npm run dev
```

The Typescript guide further says:

> INFO: The presence of the tsconfig.json in your project lets Nuxt.js
>   know you're running a TypeScript project.
>
> This file will be automatically updated with defaults value the first
>   time you're running nuxt command.

Problem:

1. The tsconfig.json file is not updated
2. And when I create a simple '/pages/test.ts' file it is not transpiled to .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There few problems. First you are missed installation of `ts-node`.

Also please create an empty tsconfig.json file without any content. The docs was updated and its mentioned there. That should fix your problems

Comment: Both problems still persist. The tsconfig.json is not updated as well as the /pages/test.ts is not transpiled to a .js file. Now, I am also getting a new error 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' which is probably coming from the Vuetify library. 

Suggestion: create-nuxt-app should have the option to select between ts and js builds - like the vue-cli has.

Comment: @Besto I have tried and with empty tsconfig it do update. Check again

Comment: Yes it does create tsconfig when I tried with no other options in the create-nuxt-app. Then I tried various other combinations. The problem arises when we select Express as our custom server. However even when the tsconfig is created I don't see the .ts file being transpiled to .js file.

Comment: @Besto pages should be vue files, not ts, see nuxt examples https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/examples/typescript/pages/index.vue

Comment: Oh! I thought since we are using webpack in nuxt, it will automatically transpile ALL ts files into js, then allow us to import those js files in our vue templates before making the bundles. Can you please show me how to achieve this.

Comment: @Besto it will do that if you import from ts file. So it trabspile only files that are used. If you simply create ts file and don't use it anywhere it won't be trandpiled and bundled

Comment: As suggested in this answer, `yarn add --dev ts-node` fixed it for me.